# How to upload image using angularjs in Core C#

Tags: c#, angularjs

I get the file in `console.log(file);` but I don't know how to pass it Webservice and what code I should write that will upload my Files?

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                    var modelSetter = model.assign;

                element.bind('change', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            debugger;
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            //alert();
            debugger;
            console.log(fd);
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {                    
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
            .success(function () {
            })

            .error(function () {
            });
        }
    }]);


      $scope.uploadFile = function () { // This Function will Call when Click on upload button after selecting a file.
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            console.log(file);
            var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:25204/AdminOperation.asmx/Upload", //Url of webservice/api/server
                promise = fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            promise.then(function (response) {
                $scope.serverResponse = response;
            }, function () {
                $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
            })
        };
```